# How to know that app is running in background

Tags: java, android, notifications

I trying to make a notification system for my app. For that i want to know that is my running in background or not if yes than show the notification.

I want to do this all in a intent service.

I have a separate class for notifications so it will be good if anyone give a static function returning a boolean.

Thanks !!

Comment: I want the status in Intent Service.

Comment: Please rewrite your question and note all important details related to your issue.